# Slow performance for presentViewController - depends on complexity of presentING controller?

Tags: ios, iphone, performance, cocoa-touch, instruments

I am presenting a view controller:

```
SCAAboutController2 *controller = [[SCAAboutController2 alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
UINavigationController *navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:controller];
[self presentViewController:navController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

The device hangs for 3-4 seconds before presenting. I have attempted to diagnose this using Instruments, but it seems most of the time is spent in `main` -

[image]

Here is the same profile but with System Libraries unhidden:

[image]

None of these messages are recognizable to me, so I'm not sure how to start debugging my performance issue.

I read elsewhere that I should check that the main code is executing on the main thread. However, the following change is not improving anything:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        SCAAboutController2 *controller = [[SCAAboutController2 alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
        UINavigationController *navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:controller];
        [self presentViewController:navController animated:YES completion:nil];
    });
```

I've quickly run out of ideas on how to progress. How might I investigate further, and/or what might be the root cause of the slow presentation?

**Edit**

Some confusing discoveries:

- I've removed all code from the presented view controller. The performance is unaffected.
- I have another controller which I present from the same place via a different button. It is equally slow.
- the presenting**ing** controller has quite a lot of subviews and constraints - even some child view controllers. Removing the code that populates these resolves the issue.
- nothing is added in the `viewWillDisappear` of the presenting controller.

**Edit 2**

I have discovered that the issues centers around a series of layout constraints I add in the main (presenting) controller. Specifically, I loop through some child controllers (of type `teamController`) and add the constraint:

```
[self.browser addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:teamController.view
                                                         attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth
                                                         relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                            toItem:self.browser
                                                         attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth
                                                        multiplier:1
                                                          constant:0]];
```

There are only 10 child controllers. Also strange: I have no such issues if I use the following instead:

```
[self.browser.contentView addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:teamController.view
                                                                     attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth
                                                                     relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                                        toItem:nil
                                                                     attribute:NSLayoutAttributeNotAnAttribute
                                                                    multiplier:1
                                                                      constant:200]];
```

I am still very confused as to why these constraints would cause the presentation of *another* modal to hang, and why one variation of the constraint behaves drastically differently to the other.

Comment: UI is always executed in main thread

Comment: NSIS* is related to the Autolayout engine. What happens in the presented view controller? How are the views laid out? How many subviews are there?

Comment: Thanks for the tip - please see my edit. I have some layout code I could optimize, but its in the present*ing* controller :/

Comment: @BenPackard Did you get any solution. If so please post an answer to this question.

Comment: No working solution.

Answer (score 63):

Not sure this was the original author's problem but here is something that solved a similar problem for me: I was trying to present a view from `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` and I had to call `deselectRowAtIndexPath` before. If this may help someone...

Comment: Could you clarify a bit more what u wanna say?

Comment: Same thing happened here. When populating it from inside of didSelectRowAtIndexPath, the controller would take some seconds to show app. When populating it from any different part, it would work normally. Adding deselectRowAtIndexPath inside the didSelectRowAtIndexPath worked, I'm still looking to the cause but this temporarily fix the issue.

Comment: Just adding tableView.deselectRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated: false) before self.presentViewController did fix it for me. Anybody got an explanation?

Comment: This fixed the issue for me as well, I would be interested in any further explanation.

Comment: This solved my problem too, god only knows why this has any affect. Can anyone explain?

Comment: Same think for me, adding deselect shows the alert fast.  tableView.deselectRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated: false)
present_validation_alert

Comment: I think this is a possible explanation. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21075540/presentviewcontrolleranimatedyes-view-will-not-appear-until-user-taps-again

Comment: As this answer is getting slightly popular, let me mention that calling `[super didSelectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath]` may be a cleaner way to achieve the same results.

Comment: the deselectRowAtIndexPath fix my problem BUT
after reading this solution (which is crazyyyyy  when we dont understand what we are doing), I change to  dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
///the code in didSelect....
});
and it's works also.

Comment: My problem was using animated: true, so it turns out setting it to false is important

Comment: yes，works like a charm，i use presentViewController in tableview‘s didselect method， and the presenting is delayed in ios13 ，so i move the present code to a button 's action ,everything is ok

Answer (score 7):

Your app is unresponsive because of several add and remove operation on a set. If you do any heavy processing on main thread the app gets block and becomes unresponsive.

Short ans is you have a loop which is adding objects in a set and its doing that on the main thread which is making your app slow.

If you look at your instruments the view loading buttons and rendering is pretty fast. 
initWithFrame , viewDidLoad is taking less than 4% of overall of time. The majority of the time is taken by NSISVairable release and retain which is done around 500 times. So you are doing something with your collection object and probably its in a loop. retain and release takes time and should not be done on main thread.

Simple solution is :

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue( DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
  // do all the heavy lifting here in background thread. 
}
```

Why does the following code does not improve anything :

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        SCAAboutController2 *controller = [[SCAAboutController2 alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
        UINavigationController *navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:controller];
        [self presentViewController:navController animated:YES completion:nil];
    });
```

because you are already doing this stuff in main thread and you need to call main_queue on in background thread. You should not do any UI stuff on background thread.

Comment: Thanks, I will take a look for any places where I might be manipulating NSSets. Please also see my edit - I have removed all code from the presented controller and the performance is not improved.

Comment: @BenPackard I would be helpful If you add some code of SCAAboutController2 which is manipulating data or having loops.

Comment: SCAAboutController2 is empty

Answer (score 5):

I had similar problem where the callback was on a different thread than the main thread. Using

```
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                 Your_UI_update_function()
            }
```

solves the slow UI update problem for me.

Answer (score 4):

Adding the line:

`CFRunLoopWakeUp(CFRunLoopGetCurrent());`

After:

`[self presentViewController:navController animated:YES completion:nil];`

Fixed the issue for me.

Answer taken from [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30787046/982195). Found thanks to the comment by [Eugene H](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1495663/eugene-h).

Answer (score 0):

I know I posting the answer year late. But if it is helpful for anybody else.

Try putting (swift code)

```
self.view.layer.shouldRasterize = true;
self.view.layer.rasterizationScale = UIScreen.mainScreen().scale;
```

for the view controller that being presented (and if it doesn't work there try putting it on the parent as well. I have put it on the both, it just helps smoothen all the other animations as well)

Hope this helps.

Comment: add this in 'viewWillAppear' or 'viewDidLoad' ?

Comment: try adding it in viewDidAppear