# Need to double tap on cell to present modally VC

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, modalviewcontroller

I am generating table cell.

```
cell2 = settingsTableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "ModuleCell", for: indexPath) as! ModuleCell
```

It looks fine, the cell has `tag = 2000`.

In `override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)`, I am checking the tag end `if tag == 2000` I want to present modal view. I am doing that in this way

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
let modalView = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ModalView")
present(modalView, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Then in modalView I have a button which should dismiss modalView, what's happening as expected.

```
@IBAction func saveAndClosePopup(_ sender: UIButton) {
        UserDefaults.standard.removeObject(forKey: "ActiveCantachoOptions")
        UserDefaults.standard.set(Modules.activeCantachoOptions, forKey: "ActiveCantachoOptions")

        self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
```

However, when I want to immediately present modalView again, sometimes it's okay, but sometimes I need to hit two times on the cell, which should show modalView. After the first hit, there is no difference if I hit the cell again in 1 second or in 30 seconds. The modalView will appear after the second one. What is the cause?

Comment: it will help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22585416/slow-performance-for-presentviewcontroller-depends-on-complexity-of-presenting

Comment: Since you're overriding `tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)`, do you call the super method?

Comment: have you added any tap/long tap gesture recogisers to the view controller at all? I have seen these interfere with cell selection a few times before

Comment: @Crazyrems well, I don't think so if in didSelectRowAt call the super is necessary, but I may be wrong.

Comment: @Scriptable there is no any tap gesture recogniser added.

Comment: @DSDharma I think there is much more better now, when followed. 
deselectRow made it works. I will test more

Comment: @Micgal you don't need to if the method is a call to a delegate, but here you're subclassing `UITableViewController`, wich implements lots of things under the hood _(like autosizing cells)_.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) 
{


  let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
  let modalView = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ModalView")

    self.present(modalView, animated: true) {        

       tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: false)

 }
}
```