# button action does not work for the first time tapped

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton

I have created a button in my storyboard. And created an action and outlet for it. I do some tasks in action of a button. But the button action is performed only from the second time.

Here's my code for the button action:

```
@IBAction func sendButtonTapped(sender: UIButton) {

        let domain = String(txtEmail.text!.characters.suffix(9))

        if txtEmail.text == "" || domain != "nu.edu.kz" {
            let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Error", message: "Please enter your valid nu.edu.kz e-mail", preferredStyle: .Alert)
            let defaultAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: .Cancel, handler: nil)
            alertController.addAction(defaultAction)

            self.presentViewController(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
        } else {

            if sendButton.currentTitle != "Reset Password has been sent" {

                FIRAuth.auth()?.sendPasswordResetWithEmail(self.txtEmail.text!, completion: { (error) in

                    print(error?.localizedDescription)

                    if error != nil {

                        print(error?.localizedDescription)
                    } else {

                        print("reset password email has been sent")

                        self.sendButton.setTitle("Reset Password has been sent", forState: .Normal)

                    }
                })
            }
        }
    }
```

And as I said before I have created an outlet for my button and textfield:

```
@IBOutlet weak var sendButton: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var txtEmail: UITextField!
```

P.S. I use Swift 2.3 here. Actually, I want to setTitle of the button to the new one. And this changes after tapping for the second time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please refer to this:

[presentViewController:animated:YES view will not appear until user taps again](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21075540/presentviewcontrolleranimatedyes-view-will-not-appear-until-user-taps-again)

Probably want you want to do is call  `presentViewController(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)`
 explicitly on main thread

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
     self.presentViewController(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: I forgot to say what I am trying to do, sorry for that :) I want to setTitle to the new one. I will edit my question

Comment: And this does worked for me. Thank you! Can you please explain how that helps?