# Presenting ViewController will be loaded but does not appear

Tags: ios, swift

The presenting ViewController seems to load, but the screen is actually not reloading. After I touch the screen the ViewController is visible.
This is my `instantiateViewController` code:

```
let v = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "BrowsingDaragaViewController") as! BrowsingDaragaViewController
self.present(v, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

In the `BrowsingDaragaViewController` is no additional code. The  `viewDidAppear()`  function is not called until I touch the screen. 
I'm using Xcode 9 with Swift4.

**edit:**

presentation code is in `tableview(didSelectedRow at indexPath)` but when i but it in button action it works fine

Comment: Can you show to us your screens in your storyboard?

Comment: i replace it with new view controller with no more elements but still the same problem

Comment: In current view Take one button and in the click event put BrowsingDaragaViewController push code

Comment: in pushing it works fine

Comment: Are you sure to be on the Main thread ?

Comment: yes in tableview didselectedrow
    i now try to present anothe viewController but the same problem

Comment: @iPatel in button action it works good but i need to use it in tableview(didselectedRow)

Comment: finally i found it interesting IOS bug https://stackoverflow.com/a/30787046/5212377

Answer (score 1):

If you have used any gesture recogniser then remove it and check if it causing the problem?

And if You are not using gesture recogniser then use below code in `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`

```
// Your stuff
DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
   self.present(yourViewControllerHere, animated: true, completion: nil)
})
// Your stuff
```

**OR**

Still facing issue then make sure you tableView has single selection set in your XIB or StoryBoard.

Comment: more details in this link 
 https://stackoverflow.com/a/30787046/5212377