# Cells don't show up in a table view until minimal scrolling or tap (NOTE: nothing happens on a background thread)

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiviewcontroller, uicollectionview

I have a horizontally scrollable `UICollectionView` with three cells each of which are different subclasses of `UICollectionViewCell`. Each one of these cells contains a `UITableView`.

Inside of the first two cells, my table view cells are the same subclasses of `UITableViewCell` and have just a `UIImageView`. I use it to set its `backgroundColor`. Inside of the third cell, my `table view`'s cells are different subclasses of `UITableViewCell` than in the previous two. They have both a `UILabel` and a `UIImageView`. The label has some dummy text, and I set `imageView`'s `backgroundColor` to some color, again.

In order to follow `MVC` pattern, I use my `UIViewController` as a `data source` and a `delegate` for both `collection view`, and `table view`. Here is the code of `UIViewController`:

```
 class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

let collectionViewCellId = "collectionViewCell"
let tableViewCellId = "tableViewCell"
let collectionViewCellId2 = "collectionViewCellId2"
let collectionViewCellId3 = "collectionViewCellId3"
let tableViewCellDif = "tableViewCellDif"
var collectionViewIndex: Int?

@IBOutlet weak var collectionView: UICollectionView! {
    didSet {
        collectionView.delegate = self
        collectionView.dataSource = self
        collectionView.isPagingEnabled = true
    }
}


//MARK: UITableViewDataSource

public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 5
}

public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let colors: [UIColor] = [.red, .green, .purple, .orange, .blue]
    let colors2: [UIColor] = [.blue, .brown, .yellow, .magenta, .cyan]


    if collectionViewIndex == 0 {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: tableViewCellId, for: indexPath) as! TableViewCell
        cell.colorForImageView = colors[indexPath.row]
         return cell
    } else
    if collectionViewIndex == 1 {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: tableViewCellId, for: indexPath) as! TableViewCell
        cell.colorForImageView = colors2[indexPath.row]
         return cell 
    } else
    if collectionViewIndex == 2 {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: tableViewCellDif, for: indexPath) as! TableViewCellDifferent
        cell.colorForImageView = colors2[indexPath.row]
        return cell
    } else {
        return UITableViewCell()
    }

  }

 }

//MARK: UICollectionViewDataSource

extension ViewController: UICollectionViewDataSource {
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView,    numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 3
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    let identifier: String
    if indexPath.item == 0 {
        identifier = collectionViewCellId
    } else if indexPath.item == 1 {
        identifier = collectionViewCellId2
    } else if indexPath.item == 2 {
        identifier = collectionViewCellId3
    } else {
        identifier = ""
    }
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: identifier, for: indexPath)

    return cell
 }
}

//MARK: UICollectionViewDelegate
extension ViewController: UICollectionViewDelegate {

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, willDisplay cell: UICollectionViewCell, forItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if indexPath.item == 0 {
        let cell = cell as! CollectionViewCell
        cell.tableView.dataSource = self
        cell.tableView.delegate = self
        collectionViewIndex = 0
    }
    if indexPath.item == 1 {
        let cell = cell as! CollectionViewCell2
        cell.tableView.dataSource = self
        cell.tableView.delegate = self
        collectionViewIndex = 1
    }
    if indexPath.item == 2 {
        let cell = cell as! CollectionViewCell3
        cell.tableView.dataSource = self
        cell.tableView.delegate = self
        collectionViewIndex = 2
        print (collectionViewIndex)
    }
  }

}

//MARK: UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout
extension ViewController: UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
    let layout = collectionViewLayout as! UICollectionViewFlowLayout
    layout.minimumInteritemSpacing = 0
    layout.minimumLineSpacing = 0

    return CGSize(width: collectionView.frame.width, height: collectionView.frame.height)
}

}
```

As I stated in a title of the question, **nothing** happens on a background thread. I, basically, only set the `backgroundColor` of `table view`'s cells.

The problem is that inside the `collection view`'s third cell (and only inside of there), my `table view` dequeues its cells only after a minor scroll or tap happens. Here is how it looks like:

[image]

I can't figure out why this happens. Maybe, this happens because inside of the third cell of the `collection view`, my `table view`'s cells are instances of different subclass than inside of the first two?

**EDITED**

I could solve the problem by reloading the `table view` before before showing the `collection view`'s each cell but I'm not sure that this is the most efficient solution. Here is the code:

```
 //MARK: UICollectionViewDelegate
 extension ViewController: UICollectionViewDelegate {

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, willDisplay cell: UICollectionViewCell, forItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if indexPath.item == 0 {
        let cell = cell as! CollectionViewCell
        cell.tableView.dataSource = self
        cell.tableView.delegate = self
        cell.tableView.reloadData()
        collectionViewIndex = 0
    }
    if indexPath.item == 1 {
        let cell = cell as! CollectionViewCell2
        cell.tableView.dataSource = self
        cell.tableView.delegate = self
        cell.tableView.reloadData()
        collectionViewIndex = 1
    }
    if indexPath.item == 2 {
        let cell = cell as! CollectionViewCell3
        cell.tableView.dataSource = self
        cell.tableView.delegate = self
        cell.tableView.reloadData()
        collectionViewIndex = 2
    }
  }

}
```

If you know a better way, I would appreciate your help.

Comment: What about calling cell.tableView.reloadData() inside 
if indexPath.item == 2 {
        let cell = cell as! CollectionViewCell3
        cell.tableView.dataSource = self
        cell.tableView.delegate = self
        collectionViewIndex = 2
        print (collectionViewIndex)
    }

? Of course, after setting the delegate and datasource.

Comment: @crom87, I've done that, already, see edited question. The problem is, I'm not sure that this is the best solution

Comment: Is the method public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {, called with collectionViewIndex == 2?

Comment: Have you tried setting tableView `.delegate` and `.dataSource` inside `cellForItemAt` instead of `willDisplay cell`?

Comment: @crom87, if you mean whether the method is called within `collectionViewIndex == 2`, then it isn't until I scroll the table view a little bit. That is the reason why the problem occurs, but I can't figure out why the method doesn't get called here, whereas on previous cells it does

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I gave this a try, and saw the same results. So, I moved your collection view cell "setup" code from `willDisplay cell:` to `cellForItemAt` and it fixed the problem.

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    if indexPath.item == 0 {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: collectionViewCellId, for: indexPath) as! CollectionViewCell
        cell.tableView.dataSource = self
        cell.tableView.delegate = self
        collectionViewIndex = 0
        return cell
    }
    if indexPath.item == 1 {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: collectionViewCellId2, for: indexPath) as! CollectionViewCell2
        cell.tableView.dataSource = self
        cell.tableView.delegate = self
        collectionViewIndex = 1
        return cell
    }
    // if we get here, indexPath.item must equal 2
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: collectionViewCellId3, for: indexPath) as! CollectionViewCell3
    cell.tableView.dataSource = self
    cell.tableView.delegate = self
    collectionViewIndex = 2
    return cell

}
```

Now, since you're not showing your code for your tableview cells, it's *possible* there might be another issue, but this worked for me:

```
class TableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet var theImageView: UIImageView!

    var colorForImageView: UIColor = UIColor.gray {
        didSet {
            self.theImageView.backgroundColor = colorForImageView
        }
    }

}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. This works. Honestly speaking, I can't understand why I didn't try this at first. P.s my table view cell code is almost identical to yours, so the problem was in setting the tableView's data source and delegate

Answer (score 0):

You can try to dequeue CollectionViewCell or TableViewCell explicitly on the main thread

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
   let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: identifier, for: indexPath)
}
```

or

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: tableViewCellDif, for: indexPath) as! TableViewCellDifferent
    cell.colorForImageView = colors2[indexPath.row]
}
```

It could help to wake up the main thread

But in general, it would be much easier if a data source for the table view was inside collection view cell

Comment: Well, shouldn't dequeuing happen on a main thread by definition because it is an operation that affects `UIView`s? And I know that by making the collection view's cell a data source (and/or a delegate), we can control all this processes easier, however, that violates MVC pattern, and isn't considered as a good design.

Comment: It should happen on the main thread, but I encounter a bug once like here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21075540/presentviewcontrolleranimatedyes-view-will-not-appear-until-user-taps-again/30787046#30787046

Comment: And putting data source inside collection view cell doesn't violate MVC. In this case, UITableViewCell class is a controller, and it has a model and a view.

Comment: In the documentation it is said that UITableViewCell inherits from UIView, so it is basically a subclass of UIView. That's why it is a view, not a controller. A subclass of UITableViewController is a controller because it controls how its views (usually, cells) behave and what data they should contain (model part).

Comment: I've tried your suggestion, but it didn't change the behaviour of the table view

Comment: UITableViewCell has a contentView property so logic controlling this view acts as a Controller.