# back button navigation very slow

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller

I am using following code to push viewcontroller from another viewcontroller .

```
ProductDetailViewController * productDetails = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ProductDetailViewController"];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:productDetails animated:YES];
```

Now this is the code gets called on tap of back button

```
[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

Problem is when I tap on back button, navigation becomes very slow. Any suggestion to solve this.

Comment: Are you doing any task in ProductDetailViewController's -viewWillDisappear or -viewDidDisappear.

Comment: no. I am not doing anything

Comment: And what about viewDidLoad and viewWillAppear of first view controller ?

Comment: Try on main thread

Comment: You should check this as well...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8833631/pushviewcontroller-animation-is-slow-choppy

Comment: @Pushkraj in viewDidAppear I am getting data from webservice

Comment: @user3575114 tried on main thread but no use.

Comment: Ok, try to call that method as well on dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{ }); so UI will not block.

Comment: You should try placing the web service logic in -viewDidLoad.

Comment: I need to refresh data so thats the reason added in viewDidAppear

Comment: Well this might be the reason. U sure you're not blocking the main thread in your web service logic?

Comment: "Refresh Data"...are you using a tableview to display data..is "reloadData" called on main thread?

Comment: yes reloaddata is called on mainthread

Comment: Might be similar issue....http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19917928/uinavigationcontroller-pushviewcontroller-pauses-freezes-midway-through

Comment: Have you tried this on real iOS device, inspite-of Simulator ?